# How to convert List<Double> to Byte[] in C#

Tags: c#, unsafe-pointers

Convertion from Double[] src to Byte[] dst
can be efficiently done in C# by fixed pointers:

```
fixed( Double* pSrc = src)
{
  fixed( Byte* pDst = dst)
  {
    Byte* ps = (Byte*)pSrc;
    for (int i=0; i < dstLength; i++)
    {
      *(pDst + i) = *(ps +i);
    }
  }
}
```

How can I do the same for List src ?
I.e. how can I get fixed pointer to array Double[]
included in List ?
Thanks.

Comment: I didn't even know that something like that exists...

Comment: I am more curious why would you do that through pointers?

Answer (score 2):

I have used these helper methods before:

```
byte[] GetBytesBlock(double[] values)
{
   var result = new byte[values.Length * sizeof(double)];
   Buffer.BlockCopy(values, 0, result, 0, result.Length);
   return result;
}

double[] GetDoublesBlock(byte[] bytes)
{
   var result = new double[bytes.Length / sizeof(double)];
   Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, result, 0, bytes.Length);
   return result;
}
```

An example:

```
List<double> myList = new List<double>(){ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0};

//to byte[]
var byteResult = GetBytesBlock(myList.ToArray());

//back to List<double>
var doubleResult = GetDoublesBlock(byteResult).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you are intending, but I think ... you want
`System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal.StructToPtr`.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the `ToArray()` method on the `List<Double>` object to get a `Double[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to get the reference to the private T[] _items field, in the List instance.

**Warning**: In your code snippet, you need to make sure dstLength is the minimum of dst and src lengths  in bytes, so that you don't try to copy more bytes than what are available. Probably you do so by creating dst with exactly the needed size to match the src, but your snippet doesn't make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `List<T>.ToArray()` method and operate on the resulting array.

Comment: I don't think this is desirable, as it implies a third array is created and values are copied to it, so the work and memory consumption is doubled.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just access the list as usual?

```
List<double> list = new List<double>();
list.Add(Math.PI);
list.Add(34.22);

byte[] res = new byte[list.Count * sizeof(double)];

unsafe
{
    fixed (byte* pres = res)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            *(((double*)pres) + i) = list[i];
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it thoroughly and i seldomly need unsafe code, but it seems to work fine.

**Edit:** here is another (imo preferable) solution, without unsafe code:

```
int offset = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    long num = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(list[i]);

    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        res[offset++] = (byte)num;
        num >>= 8;
    }
}
```

Comment: The conversion (double*)pres reside in the cycle. So will it be more efficiently to get the pointer to private T[] _items field in the List<Double> instance and convert it to (Byte*) only once ?

Comment: @user536443 As far as I know the “conversion” is effectively a no-op (and thus has no impact on performance). The data in memory is just copied over and interpreted in a different way. Your code does it one byte at a time, mine will do it one double at a time.

Comment: @user536443 Accessing the list this way may be a bit more expensive than using a pointer (because of the range checks). Apart from that I think it is pretty much the same. If you >really< need the performance, then measure execution time. Anything else is speculative. And don't optimize if there is no need for it.

Comment: Thank you. I'l try out both solutions

Answer (score 0):

This might work, but you will have a data loss- content of the array will be 3 and 34 .

```
    List<double> list = new List<double>();
    list.Add(Math.PI);
    list.Add(34.22);

    byte[] arr = (from l in list
                  select (byte)l).ToArray<byte>();
```